# how print unique values in 2 columns using php

Tags: php, sql

two columns

```
user_id      purchase_item
1              watch
1              TV
2             watch
2             fridge
2             Toys
```

when i use distinct comand in sql 
same as it is show data but i want to following

```
user_id:1
purchase_item:watch
tv
user_id:2
purchase_item:watch
fridge
Toys
```

means i want user id print only one time so how it is possible in php
plz help me and tell coding please

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to show us what you've tried, the current output and the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it completely in Mysql you can use  aggregation to get items as comma separated list per user

```
select user_id, group_concat(purchase_item) purchase_item
from table
group by user_id
```

this will give you results like

```
user_id      purchase_item
1             watch,TV     
2             watch,fridge,Toys
```

> Also note using [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) the result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet

But its better if you do this in php just get the ordered results and apply your logic to show user_id only once for multiple purchase_item related to that user

```
select * from table order by user_id asc
```

Comment: no your code not working only show one purchase item if you know php code plz tell me

Comment: @MazharHussain Are you sure query is not working ?Here is the working [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/695ea8/1)

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid query working but only show 1 purchase item

Comment: @MazharHussain What are you trying to say query is showing one item or you want to show one item ? And if so which item you want per user

Comment: thanks brother you are write i write in mistake there fore your query is good thanks

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid i accept your anwser ok

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid thanks brother for anwsering but if i am using SELECT * FROM TABlE                                                                                             and use php for same result plz tell if you know php coding using same result

Comment: @MazharHussain its better if you could ask a new question all the relevant details also include your expected output  and your code