# Query selected columns from two tables with a Condition clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables-

1) ****Company_Form****

[***Contract_No#***,Software_Name,Company_Name,Vendor_Code]

2) ****User_Form****

[Contract_No,***Invoice_No#***,Invoice_Date,Invoice_Amount,Invoice_Submit_Date]

Fields denoted with **#** and **bold** are primary keys.

=>The user has to enter a software name for which he wants to get the data of.

=>I have to structure a query in which I have to display the result in the following form:

**[Contract#,Software_Name,Company_Name,Invoice_No,Invoice_Date,Invoice_Submission_Date]**

Now,

- one Contract_No can contain **many Invoice_no** under its name in
  the User Form table.
- One **Contract_No** can occur one time only in
  Company_Form table
- The retrieved records have to be **group by** the latest Invoice_Date

I came to the logic that:

1. I have to first retrieve all the contract numbers with that software
   name from  Company_Form table.
2. I have to query that contract number  from User_Form table and display
   the data for each matched contract no. fetched from Company_Form
   table.

The problem is that I am unable to structure a query in SQL that can do the task for me.

Kindly help me in formulating the query.

[PS] I am using SQL with PHP.

I tried a query like:

I tried one approach as :

```
SELECT a.ContractNo,a.SoftwareName,a.CompanyName,b.InvoiceNo,b.InvoiceDate,b.InvAmount,b.InvoiceSubmitDate
            FROM Company_Form as a,User_Form as b 
            WHERE b.ContractNo IN(SELECT ContractNo FROM Company_Form WHERE 
                                SoftwareName='$Sname') AND a.ContractNo=b.ContractNo;
```

But I am getting a error that sub query returns more than 1 row.
Can I get help from this?

Comment: `I am using SQL` ... which version of SQL are you actually using?

Comment: + Tim Biegeleisen MySQL which comes with Xampp 5.6.32

Comment: see this link same question with answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975385/how-can-i-print-array-in-parallel-using-php?noredirect=1#comment82920341_47975385

Comment: +Mazhar Hussain I have to use a SQL query...not print arrays in PHP

Comment: see this only query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919297/how-print-unique-values-in-2-columns-using-php

Comment: +Mazhar Hussain Actually I am a bit new to the field so...could you please formulate a query as per the logic I have given in my question?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "The retrieved records have to be group by the latest Invoice_Date"? Do you need 1 row per Contract_No with latest Invoice_Date?

Comment: +Hasaan Mubasher  In the company_form table, one contract number corresponds to one client.There can be several clients paying for the same software..so different contract numbers can have the same software.My task is to group in descending order by invoice date that software for every contract number

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are attempting to find the most recent price of the user selected software and its corresponding invoice. Here is an approach to do this. If this is tested to your satisfaction, I can add necessary explanation.

```
select uf.Contract_No#, 
       cf.Software_Name,
       cf.Company_Name,
       uf.Invoice_No#, 
       uf.Invoice_Date,
       uf.Invoice_Amount,
       uf.Invoice_Submit_Date
from User_Form uf
inner join ( 
             -- Most recent sale of software
             select Contract_No#, max(Invoice_Date)
             from User_Form 
             group by Contract_No#
           ) latest
on ( 
    -- Filter via join for latest match records
    uf.Contract_No# = latest.Contract_No#
    and uf.Invoice_Date = latest.Invoice_Date
   )
inner join Company_Form cf
on cf.Contract_No# = uf.Contract_No#
where cf.Software_name = :software_name
```

Comment: I have just edited my question...can you please go through and help me with my query once?

Comment: Actually I want to display a full list of invoices for that particular software in descending order i.e.  the most recent invoice date should come first in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement allows your sub query to return more than one row, I would suggest you to use IN instead of = in the where clause of your main query.

Please note  that I have just looked at the query and have not fully understood the requirements.

Thanks.

Comment: The goal is to view invoice dates in descending order of that particular software.The User_Form table does not contain software name so we have to fetch all the contract numbers corresponding to the software from the Company_Form table.

Comment: The User_form table contains contract numbers so we compare if any contract no. in a row matches to those numbers fetched from Company_form.If yes that row is printed.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around for some time and finally came to the following query which works like a charm

```
SELECT a.ContractNo,a.SoftwareName,a.CompanyName,b.InvoiceNo,b.InvoiceDate,b.InvAmount,b.ISD
     FROM Company_Form as a,User_Form as b
     WHERE b.ContractNo IN (SELECT ContractNo FROM Company_Form WHERE SoftwareName='$Sname') 
                        AND a.ContractNo=b.ContractNo;
```

If anybody needs help in understanding the logic of this query,feel free to comment below.